# AWS S3 - unable to download FOLDERS from AWS S3 via web gui

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Simple problem I have been racking my brain on for days.
We have an s3 bucket, IAM user has full permission to a bucket created by that same IAM user.
User is able to download OBJECTS (single files) from the s3 bucket, but cannot download folders containing files, or folders containing folders of files.

When logging into AWS with an IAM user (same user that created the bucket), browsing to S3 console, buckets, clicking into the specific bucket, and selecting a folder, the "download" button is gray. going all the way down to the singular files contained within these directories, the IAM user is able to download single files, but we need to be able to download entire folders of files in this s3 bucket. We do not have the secret key to access via AWS-CLI and download recursively

We're working with a large set of json logs from Cloudwatch, and so there are thousands of log folders to be downloaded. Downloading specific json log files at the object level is no help here.

What am I missing?

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot download directories/folders"? How are the user trying to download them? What error did he receive?

Comment: When logging into AWS with an IAM user (same user that created the bucket), browsing to S3 console, buckets, clicking into the specific bucket, and selecting a folder, the "download" button is gray. going all the way down to the singular files contained within these directories, the IAM user is able to download single files, but we need to be able to download entire folders of files in this s3 bucket. We do not have the secret key to access via AWS-CLI and download recursively.

Comment: can you please add these additional infos directly in your post?

Comment: done, details added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot download an entire folder directly from the S3 Console.
As outlined in [the official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/download-objects.html), this functionality is available only through the CLI or API.

This isn't an issue with your IAM configuration: you can test with the root user and you'll observe that the "Download" button remains grayed out, even for the most privileged user.